# Is there any reason to use optional props in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Flow allows you to designate optional props:

```
type Props = {
    isLoggedIn?: boolean
};
```

If you don't pass in a value, then the prop will be set to "undefined".

Is it ever good practice to use these over the alternative of a required prop plus a default value? It seems strictly better to explicitly set the default rather than deal with the possibility of having an "undefined" prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing types to describe objects from a third party library or service, then it is best to describe them as accurately as possible.

If you are just writing types for your own code then it's really a design choice. For example, if you have a service which returns a JSON representation of a large collection of objects which can each contain a lot of `null` values, you could greatly reduce the parsing overhead by just omitting them from the JSON.

> It seems strictly better to explicitly set the default rather than deal with the possibility of having an "undefined" prop.

Flow will prevent you from forgetting to handle the possibly undefined values. Copying a large number of default values into a data structure may be wasteful, compared to just checking if it's missing at the point that you need to use it.

If you don't have a large number of objects and performance isn't a concern, then this might just be a matter of style or preference.

If you are strictly talking about props for a React component, then using explicit default values is mostly going to be best because it will help to make your component self-documenting. The default values will be more obvious to a user of the component, compared to being buried deep inside the implementation.